# Cant see computer in windows local network

Tags: windows, networking, directory, local

I work with local network where are 50 computers. All are conneceted by 10 switches. Inside network is local group - MSHOME where computers have one shared folder. The problem is that some but not all computers lost ability to connect to this folder. I've got an error - cant access \NAME\FOLDER . Even after I connected wire from good comp to bad the problem wouldnt solved, though they both are connected to the same switch. What should I test?

Comment: test the network connection and the sharing settings.

Comment: Maybe some firewall rules are blocking specific computers and not others

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. ipconfig /all showed me that computer with shared folder and bad computer had different gateway. When I entered in browser ip of gateway on shared computer I saw admin panel of router which I recently removed and reconnected during repair operations. Then I made a wan port on router free and this router stopped to be the gateway for my shared folder comp. After that I can access shared folder from any computer on network cause all have the same gateway address which is the ip of main router.